# Javascript: Remove last occurence of comma in span tag

Tags: javascript, html, append

I want to append *object keys* to span tag with class *result* and separate them with comma. But I can't remove last occurence of comma in text.

```
Result: <span class="result"></span>
```

Javascript:

```
for (key in obj) {
    $(".result").append(key + ",");
}
```

So, for example, instead of 1,2,3, it must be 1,2,3

Comment: your obj is an array or Object literal ?

Comment: It is object, I wrote in description that I am appending object keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try solution in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxtA4/2/) join() function of array comes in real handy

```
// if array
var ele = ["1", "2", "3"]
$(".result").append(ele.join(","));


// if object 
var ele1 = { "a": 1, "b" :2, "c" : 3}
var value = $.map(ele1, function(k, v) { return k;}).join(",")
$(".result1").append(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the "join" method in order to combine array elements with separators between them like so:

```
var sample = ["1", "2", "3"];
console.log(sample.join(","));
//outputs: 1,2,3
```

It does not work on object properties though, so you have to use Object.keys() in order to convert your object into an array of its properties (supported in most browsers).

```
$(".result").append(Object.keys(obj).join(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
var str = "1,2,3,"
str = str.slice(0,-1)
console.log(str) //"1,2,3"
```

For your `SPAN` I did this.

```
$('.result').text($('.result').text().slice(0,-1))
```

Comment: I have tried to apply slice(0,-1) to text extracted from span tag, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It will replace all trailing ','.

```
 var str = "1,2,3,"
 str.replace(/,+$/g,"")
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3fgv6/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the array methods:

```
var test = "a,b,c,,,";
var test1 = test.split(",");
while (!test1[test1.length-1]) {
  test1.pop();
}
console.log(test1);
test = test1.join(",");
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do, instead:

```
var results = (Object.keys(obj)).join(",");
$(".result").append(results);
```

Far more simpler. More efficient ;)
If you do an append in a loop, the page will be redrawn every time you add a key. That's slow.
Plus, with `Object.keys(obj)` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) you get an array with all the keys of the object, and you only need to join all elements in a string, separating it with a comma. So more concise, no?

Comment: @jbrosi already answer this, basically. Neat. This is what happen when you don't refresh the page for a while. Don't have enough reputation for comment in your answer ;)